# Delphi - TMemoryStream download content handling

Tags: delphi, memory

I am downloading a file in a TMemoryStream like this:

```
  ms := TMemoryStream.Create;
  IdHTTP1.Get('https://dl.dropbox.com/u/21226165/XE3StylesDemo/StylesDemoSrcXE2.7z', ms);
```

My question is if TMemoryStream is saving anything to the harddisk?

I know it gets saved to the harddisk once you call SaveToFile. 
But does it save anything automatically to the temp folder or something?

Comment: No, it doesn't save anything to disk (as long as the used memory is swapped to disk).

Comment: I would expect that the class will do what the name describe, and here we have a stream in memory.

Answer (score 3):

A `TMemoryStream` is simply a wrapper around heap allocated memory. As such, nothing is explicitly saved to disk. If the memory is paged out then it could be saved to the page file.

Comment: But the paging has nothing to do with the class itself. It is just a behaviour from the OS not controlled by the class.

Comment: @SirRufo Agreed. But perhaps the user thinks that heap memory can never find its way to the disk.

Answer (score 0):

`TMemoryStream` is for work with memory but if you want save directly to temp use `TFileStream` :

```
// Creates a name for a temporary file.
Function TempFileName(): string;
var
  // This buffer should be MAX_PATH characters to accommodate the path plus the terminating null character.
  lpTempFileName: array[0..MAX_PATH] of Char;
  tempdir: array[0..MAX_PATH] of Char;
begin
  GetTempPath(MAX_PATH, tempdir);
  GetTempFileName(tempdir, nil, 0, lpTempFileName);
  Result := lpTempFileName;
end;

procedure TForm1.btn1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  fs : TFileStream;
  tmpFile : string;
begin
  tmpFile := TempFileName;
  fs := TFileStream.Create(tmpFile, fmCreate);
  try
    IdHTTP1.Get('http://www.bing.com/az/hprichbg/rb/BrooklynHeights_ROW10562657125_1366x768.jpg', fs);
  finally
    fs.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Asker wants **not** to save to file

Comment: Except that, this code is very unsafe. The `Get` method can easily raise an exception and leak the stream. And the temp file generating function is missing error checking.

Comment: FWIW, Indy has its own `MakeTempFileName()` and `GetUniqueFileName()` functions in the `IdGlobalProtocols` unit.